# How to update the access token expire_at (laravel passport) in laravel 5.4 without refresh the access token

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm making a api with laravel passport, I made a token for one user with no duplicate user, I made a token to expire in 10 days, but I want to add functionality if the user is already logged in and logged on again with a different device still wearing the same token sehinnga in existing login function 2 conditions if the user logged on has not had a token or tokens expire then create a new token, if the user login is found token has not expired then the old tokens expire updates to 10 days from now without refresh token

Answer (score 0):

You can delete old tokens while creating new token or on login. First of all you need to create OauthAccessToken Model.

**For example,** 
Create following function in your user model

```
public function accessTokens() {
    return $this->hasMany(OauthAccessToken::class);
}

And then check and delete the tokens 

$user = User::whereId($id)->with('accessTokens')->first();
if ($user->accessTokens->count() > 0) {
   $user->accessTokens()->delete();
}
```